# Updating Radio Button Select on Click Parent Element in Angular

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui

Assume this model:

```
      <li ng-repeat="item in documentViews" for ={{item}}>
        <div class="col-sm-12 document-view-item" ng-click="change($index)">
          <div class="row">
            <img class="document-view-img" src="../assets/images/kml_document.png">
          </div>

          <div class="row">
              <input type="radio" ng-model="prefs.documentView" ng-value="item.value" id="{{item.value}}" name="documentView" ng-selected="prefs.documentView">
              {{item.key}}
                </input>
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>
```

And this controller:

```
angular.module('app')
  .controller('DocumentViewCtrl', function ($scope) {

    $scope.subtitle = 'Default document view';
    $scope.documentViews = [
      {
        key: 'Blah1',
        value: 'b1'
      },
      {
        key: 'Blah2',
        value: 'b2'
      },
    ];

    $scope.change = function($index) {
      console.log($scope.documentViews[$index].value);
    };
});
```

I do not want to update the radio button only when selecting the input tag, but when clicking on the higher div element where the ng-click appears. I couldn't get further than triggering a console log when a click occurs and this is fine, but I am wondering how to update the select on the radio button and thus the $scope.

Comment: there is problem in logic if you will ng-repeat the item and doesn't provide unique ng-modal to radio button.It will not work properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about something like this?

In your html:

```
  <li ng-repeat="item in documentViews" for="{{item}}">
    <div class="col-sm-12 document-view-item" ng-click="change(item)">
      <div class="row">
        <img class="document-view-img" src="../assets/images/kml_document.png">
      </div>

      <div class="row">
          <input type="radio" ng-model="prefs.documentView" ng-value="item.value" id="{{item.value}}" name="documentView" ng-selected="prefs.documentView">
          {{item.key}}
            </input>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
```

In your controller:

```
$scope.change = function(item) {
  $scope.prefs.documentView = item.value;
}
```

Comment: This works! Ah, I see I was very close to solving it, but I understand now how to set the value within a scope. Still learning Angular and thumbs up for this example!